# Problem on using $_SESSION inside HTML anchor href

Tags: php, html

I have a sample code here

```
<li><a href="<?php $_SESSION['category']= 'A'; echo 'sample.php'; ?>">A</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php $_SESSION['category']= 'B'; echo 'sample.php'; ?>">B</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php $_SESSION['category']= 'C'; echo 'sample.php'; ?>">C</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php $_SESSION['category']= 'D'; echo 'sample.php';?>">D</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php $_SESSION['category']= 'E'; echo 'sample.php';?>">E</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php $_SESSION['category']= 'F'; echo 'sample.php'; ?>">F</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php $_SESSION['category']= 'G'; echo 'sample.php';?>">G</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php $_SESSION['category']= 'H'; echo 'sample.php';?>">H</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php $_SESSION['category']= 'I'; echo 'sample.php';?>">I</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php $_SESSION['category']= 'J'; echo 'sample.php';?>">J</a></li>
```

as you can see i am trying to save into session the letter to be sent into sample.php. But even if i press 'B' what gets sent over to the sample.php is 'J' (the last letter) . tried clicking the other letters too its always 'J'.

can anybody help on what i am doing wrong?

Thank you very much

Comment: PHP executes from top to bottom and since `$_SESSION['category']= 'J';` is your final instruction then that is what is saved in the session. `echo 'sample.php';` doesn't magically know that it was supposed to be `A`, `B`, or anything for that matter because it is ultimately HTML.

Comment: Using a `GET` parameter on the link would be easier, unless you need it persistent across other pages. `<a href="sample.php?page=A">A</a></li>`

Comment: You need to pass the category through the URL since it needs to be set upon clicking the `<a>` tag like this `echo 'sample.php?category=a';` and `sample.php` needs `echo $_GET[ 'category' ];` and/or `$_SESSION['category'] = $_GET[ 'category' ];`

Comment: so by doing echo `'sample.php?category=a'` i can now simply say inside sample.php $letter= $_GET['category'] ?

Comment: Correct, that is how I'd go about doing what you're wanting.

Comment: Yes, that should be the same. Unless you need the value on pages further down the path. Also you should escape the output, something like `<marquee>Injected:(</marquee>`  could be passed in and would be executed.

Comment: Remember that PHP runs on the server when the page is being created. By the time the user clicks on something, PHP is all done.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus please post your reply so i can tag it as correct :) i got it working now. Thank you for all your help

Comment: @Barmar Yes that what i have realized. I just started learning and have not known that behavior until just now :)

Comment: @user3783243 im lost ont what you are saying, im sorry im new :)

Comment: The request variables, `$_GET`, `$_POST` etc. need to be escaped, http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php (usually) or you will be open to XSS injections, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS).

Comment: just finished skimming and you are actually correct, and must be kept in mind `"sample.php?page=sword and shield"` the page is saying  `sword%and%shield`. Can you suggest a fix so that what i take `sword and shield` without those %. I guess str_replace () ?? or is there a universal function that does every escaped character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="sample.php?value=A">A</a></li>
<a href="sample.php?value=B">A</a></li>
<a href="sample.php?value=C">A</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s because your PHP code run and return the HTML output to your browser.
Because of that, all of them are ‘J’.

For solve the problem use code like this:

```
<li><a href=“sample.php?v=A”>A</a></li>
<li><a href=“sample.php?v=B”>B</a></li>
<li><a href=“sample.php?v=C”>C</a></li>
```

And you can get v value in your sample.php with this code:

```
<?php
$linkv=$_GET[“v”];

If ($linkv==“A”)
{
   //write your code here
}

If ($linkv==“B”)
{
   //write your code here
}

If ($linkv==“C”)
{
   //write your code here
}

?>
```